# How do I use the object oriented design paradigm when building a lexer/scanner?

Tags: oop, architecture, smalltalk, lexer

I am attempting to design a small regular expression engine (in Smalltalk) to help bolster my object oriented skills.

I have scoped out some regex engines in other languages (and the Smalltalk native one) and they all seem to have a singular "Lexer" or "Scanner" class. This confuses me, as I see the lexer as a single function that should take the pattern as an input (and possibly a "syntax" object, which defines token types), and return a token stream. I am having trouble figuring out what extra functions that the interface would have, and what extra state the object would need to hold.

How can this be broken down into an object oriented design?
I should add that I seem to see this a lot when I read source code: a class with a verb+"er" added to the end of its name. It seems to go against the "proper object oriented design" that books like "Clean Code" and "Code Complete" teach.

Comment: If you're interested in Smalltalk, I highly recommend getting at least one good book on the topic. One example is, [Smalltalk Best Practice Patterns](http://stephane.ducasse.free.fr/FreeBooks/BestSmalltalkPractices/Draft-Smalltalk%20Best%20Practice%20Patterns%20Kent%20Beck.pdf) by Kent Beck.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very broad question, so we can only give you equally broad answers. Here is mine.

When thinking *Object Oriented* we try to establish a clear distinction between data and behavior. An object has both and, generally speaking, the more independent the behavior from the data the better.

These basic guiding principles not always lead to designs that look natural at first glance. The reason is that sometimes we tend to attach behavior associated with some data to the very same data. And this may hide the actual object that should own such a behavior.

A typical case of this phenomenon are algorithms. We have some data: *the algorithm inputs* and some behavior: *the algorithm output*, and think that this behavior should be attached to the data. In consequence, we struggle to implement it as a *function* of said data.

However, in most of the cases this simplistic approach is problematic. For instance, many algorithms may produce multiple outputs. Take as an example the division of two polynomials where the outputs are the quotient and the remainder. Even if the algorithm produces a single output, it might happen that we would like to ask it how long it took, or even tell it to cancel its execution and stop itself, etc.

Because of these reasons (and others of the same kind) it is always advisable to think of an algorithm as an object rather than a function. The instance variables of such an object would typically refer to

```
inputs        - "one or more depending on the algorithm"
outputs       - "idem"
auxiliary     - "for holding the algorithm internal state while running"
progress      - "for recording degree of advancement"
state         - "various uses"
```

Implementing algorithms as objects will facilitate the addition of features for:

1. Reusing the very same instance with different inputs
2. Having a place for holding the outputs
3. Providing feedback to the user
4. Telling the algorithm to cancel and stop executing (by setting its state to `#cancel`)
5. Counting the number of iterations and register other things for debugging

As you can see, algorithms as objects are much richer than algorithms as functions. This doesn't mean that you will have to resign the functional approach. Just reify the algorithm and have your client object provide a function that will use the algorithm and return the result that is relevant in that context.

Answer (score 2):

It's clear from the names Lexer/Scanner/Parser/Compiler/... that we are reifying a function. But remind that in Smalltalk, there are no functions. Just objects and messages.

The obvious objects that come in mind are of course:

- whatever nodes are composing the tree-like structure you are going to produce,
- the tokens if you want to have an intermediate Lexer,
- the grammar itself (more advanced)

But then, where will the transformation of stream of characters to whatever tree-like structure take place?

In this context, the answer from Leandro reflects some common practice. It's good to reify the algorithm for things like error handling, interactive exposition and correction of errors, etc..., but might result in more or less monolithic implementations having to deal explicitely with the states of the automaton which would not be so much appealing for a functional-language aficionado...

Try on your own first, but once you made enough progress, I highly recommend to study PetitParser, take an introduction here https://www.lukas-renggli.ch/blog/petitparser-1. You will see that somehow the grammar itself, or more exactly the nodes composing the grammar, can act as the parser, thus decomposed into elementary, simple, elegant and composable objects.